# I am using Jersey to develop RESTful webservices, which URL style is most considered most idiomatic?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I read some websites rest APIs , most urls of this APIs are just like `www.abc.com/test?param=11&param=22` however in books teaching REST, most of urls are like `www.abc.com/test/11/22` .

Whats the difference? Which is correct or better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first isn't REST [it is RPC over HTTP,](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2009/10/this-isnt-rest-this-is-rpc/) and pretty much what REST is trying to solve.

The second way is RESTful and are called [Cool URLS](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI), if you really want to do REST, this is the form you should follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking in parameters, you should use `www.abc.com/test?param1=11&param2=22`.

If you are using the URL `www.abc.com/test/11/22`, in Java Servlet, this is to direct the request to a specific Servlet for processing.